# capture the removed or replaced string in Ruby to an output file

Tags: ruby

I'm reading user ids, say ncr\yui30n, from a file and checking if that user id is present in any of the file or files , if present delete it.I'm able to do that with my code below.

```
svn_files = Dir.glob("E:\nano\*_access.txt")

value=File.open('E\new_dir\access_list.txt').read
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    print "Z ID: #{line}\n"
    svn_files.each do |file_name|
      print "checking in file:#{file_name}\n"
      text = File.read(file_name)
      replace = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '' )
      File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
    end
end
```

what I'm trying to expand with my code is,  to capture the string, say (ncr\yui30n) deleted from which file or files and from which pool that string is associated in that particular file  to an output log file.

Eg. **E:\nano\ids_access.txt**

```
# Digital created on July 2016
# Digital Owner: John Cena (jxcgo)
# Digital access: create delete access

[pool]
@rem = ncr\abc_efg_dev, ncr\abc_efg_test, ncr\jx8go5, ncr\atxe5t
@digital_owner = ncr\yui30n, ncr\bhyrl4
```

I'm trying to create output log file in below pattern

**Removed_users.log**

```
Removed user : ncr\yui30n
Removed from : ids_access.txt (if present in multiple files record that too)
Pool : @digital_owner
```

I can only come with the below piece of snippet, inside the 2nd loop :

```
 File.open("E:\Removed_users.log", "a") { |log| 
         log.puts "Removed from: #{file_name}"
         log.puts "Removed user : #{line}"
         log.puts "*" * 50 
        }
```

issues is, its recording every access file its searching but I want to capture only the file from where the string is deleted and I'm not sure how to get the pool name too, say @digital_owner in the below example.

Any suggestions please . Thanks. I'm very new to ruby and still in learning phase so please excuse if its simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your code in an `if` or `unless` statement, comparing `text` vs `replace` to see if any change (i.e. a replacement) was made; something like this:

```
svn_files = Dir.glob("E:\nano\*_access.txt")

value=File.open('E\new_dir\access_list.txt').read
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    print "Z ID: #{line}\n"
    svn_files.each do |file_name|
      print "checking in file:#{file_name}\n"
      text = File.read(file_name)
      replace = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(line)}\,\s/, '' )

      unless text == replace
        File.open("E:\Removed_users.log", "a") { |log| 
          log.puts "Removed from: #{file_name}"
          log.puts "Removed user : #{line}"
          log.puts "*" * 50 
        }
        File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
      end
    end
end
```

And since you are already making that comparison, its a good idea to include your file update in that statement too.

---

Not related to your question, but you code simplify your code changing this line:

```
File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
```

to:

```
File.write(file_name, replace)
```

Comment: Perfect, I gave a thought to 'if' loop but not about 'unless' option. Thank you for the alternate suggestion. +1